# Multiple instances of jQuery autocomplete on one page

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'd like to style each instance of jQuery's autocomplete plugin differently on each page.  Except I can't figure out how to set the styles to be different for each instance.  I can't seem to wrap the ac_* styles inside a div to identify them from the CSS.  Every change I make affects both.  Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that your problem is that the autocomplete drop-under list isn't placed inside of your placeholder... example:

```
<div class="differentStyle">
    <input type="text" class="autocomplete">
</div>
```

When the results come back, a new div is added to the page to display the results - but not inside your "differentStyle" division. It just gets added to the end of the DOM. For example:

```
<div class="differentStyle">
    <input type="text" class="autocomplete">
</div>

...
<div class="ac_results">I get added by jQuery Autocomplete!</div>
</body>
```

Reading the documentation, I would say that it will make overriding the style for two auto-complete boxes on the same page impossible:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

Comment: Thanks for the research.  Yeah it's pretty frustrating.  Is there perhaps another solution to do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: The answer from @Valentin should be accepted as that's the only solution that works. TL;DR Its not impossible.

Answer (score 16):

Use the `appendTo` option to place the autocomplete list to some custom container instead of `body`. Then you can style it. Example:

JS:

```
$('#suggestions').autocomplete({source: get_suggestions, appendTo: '#my-suggestions'})
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="suggestions">
<div id="my-suggestions"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#my-suggestions {
  position: absolute;
}

#my-suggestions .ui-autocomplete {
   foo: bar;
}
```

Comment: This is the only usable solution that allows you to style different autocompletes with different css. The rest of these replies will affect all of them.

Answer (score 6):

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-widget

add something like this:

```
selector.autocomplete( "widget" ).addClass('yourclass');
```

Answer (score 2):

solution is very easy:

```
$( "#target-input" ).autocomplete({
    open:function( event, ui ) {
      $('.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu').addClass('yourClass');
    },
    close:function( event, ui ) {
      $('.ui-autocomplete.ui-menu').removeClass('yourClass');
    }
});
```

you can put any code to class .yourClass

Comment: This won't work, it will add the class to all of the autocomplete menus on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the `_renderMenu` method. Take http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox as an example.

```
selector.data("autocomplete")._renderMenu=function(ul, items){
//do something here..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that you can easily grab the UL container if you are using jQuery UI 1.8.   To grab the UI container in 1.8, you simply add the following to your open method:

```
var $myAcInput = $("#my-acomplete-input");

...
$myAcInput.autocomplete({
  open : function(event, ui) {
    // Grab the widget that just opened:
    var $resultsContainer = $formsInput.autocomplete("widget");
    // Add a custom rendering class and use tht to style your subelements
    $resultsContainer.addClass("my-custom-results-container-class");              
    // Position the container wherever you want:
    $resultsContainer.position({at: "center bottom", 
                                my:"center top", 
                                collision: "fit", 
                                of: "#my-acomplete-input"});            
  }
  source :  etc etc etc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Was searching for something else when I happened across this post...
I managed to do this by trapping the following autocomplete events, and adding my own class into the outer  that houses the autocomplete output.  Then use CSS to format the elements as necessary.   Hope this helps somebody.

```
$input.autocomplete({
            focus : function(event, ui) {
              $(".forms-search-result").parents("ul").addClass("myClass");
              return false;
            },
            open : function(event, ui) {
              $(".forms-search-result").parents("ul").addClass("myClass");
            },
```

Example css:

```
.myClass a.ui-corner-all { font-weight:bold; }
```

Also as part of my JSON results, I simply pass back (from my JAVA AJAX Action) the HTML shell with the result embedded in it as part of the actual JSON "result".  That way I can create elaborate HTML around each results, and then use the above method to format them the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions "appendTo" was added, allowing you to select a parent element for the suggestion list.
You could create different parents (with an in or class) for your lists.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem I found out, that jquery-ui gives every instance a unique id, which is #ui-id-1, #ui-id-2, where the first autocomplete in the dom gets number 1, the second number 2 and so on. So if the order of the autocompletes is known, different styles can be applied to the different id's.